# Terms and conditions for a commerce site

Tags: ecommerce, legal, terms-of-use

I am developing a website for my partner who is currently a sole trader, presently selling on ebay but we have opted to create our own site.

I've noticed that there are many sites allowing you to purchase base-line T&Cs to be used on websites, I'm tempted to give these a go but I've heard nothing on whether they are any good or not, I know in this position it's best to seek legal advice, but the budget is tight so we really can't afford that.

Has anyone had experience with these sites? e.g. http://www.netlawman.co.uk/ecomm-it/website-terms-and-conditions.php?gclid=CPL4g8D3q6cCFQoa4Qodhj5UBg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't afford legal representation then purchasing a template from sites like you linked to above is probably the best way to go. Are they perfect? Not sure. But the odds are they will give you an excellent start on creating your own terms and conditions.

Look at it this way, is it easier to start from scratch? Or to get one already written and tweak it to suit your specific needs? With the pricing they are offering it doesn't look like you have much to lose.

Comment: Yes that was exactly my view on it, it won't be perfect but there's very little to lose, they even offer 100% money back gurantee (although that one does confuse me a lot given that we're dealing with documents...).